# send data to json from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

my json script is:

```
// add button .click
$('a.add').click(function(){ 
    $('#loader').show();
    var url = "/?"+$("form[name='jsms_add']").serialize();  
    ajx = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data:{ajax:1},  
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(r) {
            $('#loader').hide();
            if(r.r != 0){
                alert("ok");
                jsmsalert($('#alert_add'),'success',r.m);
                apendtable(r.r)
                $("tr").removeClass("odd");
                $("tr.viewrow:odd").addClass("odd");
                $("tr.editrow:odd").addClass("odd");
                $('td[colspan="7"]').remove();
            }
            else{
                jsmsalert($('#alert_add'),'error',r.m,0);                        
            }
        },
        error: function(request, status, err) {
            $('#loader').hide();
            jsmsalert($('#alert_add'),'error','error...'); 
            alert( "ERROR:  " + err + "  -  "  );
        }      
    });
```

and in my php file i have

```
$data = array(
    'r'    => '1',
    'm'    => '1',
);
json_encode($data);
```

now i want to know that how can i send a value to json that `r.r != 0` be true and my success code execute?
In Firefox the error is "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character"
this code used by another site by i don't know what happend in php file

**my problem is that how can i send some data (for example r=1) to my json, because i want to check that if r=1 (means success) do something and show text from m (message) in my page**

please help me to correct php file
thank

Comment: I think you have a fundamental missunderstanding of javascript and php here. First, that is a javascript file, not json. JSON or Javascript Object Notation is used as a transfer type between client and server in this case. Second, you serialize the form in the url you are posting to, then manually set the data that you want to post? On the server side, you could need to `echo` any results you want the javascript to be able to read

Comment: Are you even sending the data from php to javascript?

Comment: header('Content-Type: application/json'); echo json_encode($data);

Comment: this code is not for me, but this code work in another site that i dont know what happend in php file, json code is in a file with .js extention (javascript)

Comment: I suggest you read more about what you're dealing with before you continue: [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript), [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json), [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Php)

Comment: my last error for this code is  `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data`

Answer (score 1):

In your php file make sure you are echoing the encoded data,
like so:

```
$data = array(
'r'    => '1',
'm'    => '1',
);
echo json_encode($data);
```

If you don't echo the data it will not make it back to your JavaScript.
If your JavaScript is what's throwing the errors try commenting out the dataType: 'json', and console logging the return. It might be php is throwing errors that jquery is refusing to parse.

```
$.ajax({'url': url,type: 'post',data:{ajax:1}, success: function(returnData){
        console.log(returnData);
}});
```

Comment: yes i echo in my file but i have an error "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character"

Comment: my last error for this code is  `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data`

Comment: Let us know what gets logged in the console.

Comment: nothing showing in console just one time page that i sent "/?" shown

Comment: I don't understand please provide more data